# Вывод последних комментариев из заданных постов

Tags: sql, wordpress

Имеется php код выводящий последние комментарии.

```html
<?php 
function last_comments($src_count=5, $src_length=50) {
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, post_password, comment_ID,
comment_post_ID, comment_author, user_id, comment_content, comment_approved,
comment_type, 
SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,$src_length) AS com_excerpt 
FROM $wpdb->comments 
LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID = $wpdb->posts.ID)
WHERE comment_approved = '1' AND comment_type = '' AND post_password = '' 
ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC
LIMIT $src_count";
$comments = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
$comment->com_excerpt = strip_tags( $comment->com_excerpt );
$output .= "<li>";
$output .= "<b>" .$comment->comment_author. "</b>";
$output .= ": <a href=\"" . get_permalink($comment->ID) . "#comment-" . $comment->comment_ID
. "\" >" . $comment->com_excerpt . "</a>…</li>";
}
$output .= "</li>"; 
echo $output;
}
last_comments();
?>
```

Что и куда в него нужно добавить, чтобы он выводил комменты из заданных постов, или может категорий. Буду очень благодарен за помощь .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в этой строчке условия выборки, добавляете нужное в конце что-то типа: `AND comment_ID = 'нужный id'`

```
WHERE comment_approved = '1' AND comment_type = '' AND post_password = ''
```

это если насчет условия "заданных постов, или может категорий" из тех полей что вижу в запросе.

```
comment_ID = "здесь id коммента"
comment_type = "здесь тип комментария"
category_name = "название категории"
post id = "id поста"

post_title IN ('заголовок 1', 'заголовок 2', 'заголовок 3')
```

Comment: если по параметру comment_ID, то это получается я сам лично должен id каждого комментария вписывать же, не ? а параметр category_name или post id как то можно сюда грамотно прописать ?

Comment: в общем добавил параметр:  AND post_title = 'пост пример 1' и о чудо, в виджете начали выводиться комменты с поста под названием "пост пример 1", но как указать сразу несколько наименований постов, не подскажите синтаксис ?

Comment: добавила в ответ category_name или post id  и синтаксис выборки нескольких наименований